# Configure php project in apache in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache

How to configure my php project with apache2 in ubuntu?
When i am Enter my publicIP my page need to load?
I am new to config with apache and php

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: There are many tutorials and How-To's to be found on the internet. Search for them, work through a few. There is no sense in us copy&pasting all that here just for you.